I don't get data while passing it through arguments. flutter
I don't get data while passing it through arguments. I pass Model of certin item to view detail of each one, but when i pass it I get null, I receive data from server in picturesview but when try to pass it to pictures detail view i got null..
here is my route manger
class AppRoutes {
  static Route onGenerate(RouteSettings settings) {
    switch (settings.name) {
      case RoutesName.splashView:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => const SplashView(),
        );

      case RoutesName.homeView:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => const HomeView(),
        );


      case RoutesName.picturesView:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => const PicturesView(),
        );

      case RoutesName.picturesDetailView:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) {
            final args = settings.arguments as GalleryList?;
            return PicturesDetailView(item: args);
          },
        );

   

      default:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => unDefineRoute(),
        );
    }
  }

  static Widget unDefineRoute() {
    return const Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text('Route not found!'),
      ),
    );
  }
}

here is my pictures view
class PicturesView extends StatelessWidget {
  const PicturesView({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          CustomAppForMedicalFile(
            text: 'pics'.tr(),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: BlocConsumer<HomeBloc, HomeState>(
              listener: (context, state) {
                if (state.getGalleryStatus == ScreenStatus.failure) {
                  myToast(
                      text: state.getGalleryFailures!.message,
                      state: ToastStates.error);
                }
              },
              builder: (context, state) {
                if (state.getGalleryStatus == ScreenStatus.loading) {
                  return const Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }
                var galleryItems = state.galleryModel?.galleryList ?? [];
                return GridView.builder(
                  itemCount: galleryItems.length,
                  gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                    crossAxisCount: 2,
                    crossAxisSpacing: 10,
                  ),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        print("AAAAA : ${galleryItems[index].title}");
                        Navigator.pushNamed(
                          context,
                          RoutesName.picturesDetailView,
                          arguments: galleryItems[index],
                        );
                      },
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                            child: Image.network(
                              "${Constant.apiBaseUrl}/${galleryItems[index].img}",
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                              height: 150.h,
                              width: double.infinity,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            galleryItems[index].title ?? '',
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: Styles.textStyle14.copyWith(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


here is my pictures detail view
class PicturesDetailView extends StatelessWidget {
  const PicturesDetailView({super.key, this.item});

  final GalleryList? item;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final GalleryList? item =
        ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as GalleryList?;

    print("Received argument: $item");

    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: BlocConsumer<HomeBloc, HomeState>(
          listener: (context, state) {
            if (state.getGalleryStatus == ScreenStatus.failure) {
              const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
          },
          builder: (context, state) {
            if (state.getGalleryStatus == ScreenStatus.loading) {
              return const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }
            return Column(
              children: [
                CustomAppForMedicalFile(
                  text: 'branch'.tr(),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0.r),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      // ClipRRect(
                      //   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                      //   child: Image.network(
                      //     "${Constant.apiBaseUrl}/${item?.img}",
                      //     fit: BoxFit.fill,
                      //     width: double.infinity,
                      //     height: 400.h,
                      //   ),
                      // ),
                      Text(item?.title ?? ''),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


please help..
I don't get data while passing it through arguments. I pass Model of certin item to view detail of each one, but when i pass it I get null, I receive data from server in picturesview but when try to pass it to pictures detail view i got null..

What if you remove final GalleryList? item = ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as GalleryList?; and use item passed as a parameter of PicturesDetailView instead?

Great! Let me write an answer so you can validate it

In PicturesDetailView, you can remove the line
    final GalleryList? item =
        ModalRoute.of(context)?.settings.arguments as GalleryList?;

and use item passed as a parameter of PicturesDetailView instead
